# How to make bottom tab bar in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Here i'm sending the image of my bottom tab navigation.
How to create this kind of bottom tab navigation in react native.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeEN2.png)

My code is like this...

```
<BottomTab.Navigator
   initialRouteName={Constants.EMPTY_SCREEN}
   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
   screenOptions={({navigation, route}) => ({})}>
   <BottomTab.Screen
      name={Constants.HOME_SCREEN}
      component={EmptyScreen}
      options={{
         tabBarLabel: 'Home',
         headerShown: false,
         tabBarActiveTintColor: Theme.colors.tabBarColor1,
         tabBarInactiveTintColor: Theme.colors.tabBarColor2,
         tabBarStyle: {
             paddingBottom: RFValue(8), height: RFValue(50)
         },
         tabBarLabelStyle: {
             fontFamily: Theme.fontFamily.fontPoppinsMedium,
             fontSize: Theme.fontSize.size10,
         },
         tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
           return (
             <Image
               style={{height: RFValue(20), width: RFValue(20)}}
               source={ focused ? ic_eye_on : ic_eye_off }
             />
           );
         },
       }}
    />
</BottomTab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Check doc https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbar